# Do not use the following characters: < > ( ) [ ] ; : , \ in email validation pattern

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

I am using regx email validation pattern in my angular application. As per requirement I Do not want the following characters: `< > ( ) [ ] ; : , \`

I am using below pattern.

```
let emailPattern = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;
```

Can some one help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this Regex:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

or refer to the following question and its answers: [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank u it worked for me. I have another one requirement i.e As long as they are not the first character in the e-mail address, hyphens ( – ), underscores ( _ ), periods ( . ),

Comment: @dnyaneshwarsuryawanshi You mean to say hypens, underscores and periods should be allowed if they are not the first character, right?

Comment: only letters (a-z), hyphen(-), underscore(_), number, and periods for email address allowed.

Comment: The above Regex allows letters, numbers, periods, hyphen and underscore.

Comment: @ Miral Kumbhani yes it working for me.Thank u very much.

Comment: @ Miral can you help me again I don't want !
^
$
&
*   this special charater in my email id but now they are accepting .can you plz help me here

Comment: @dnyaneshwarsuryawanshi try this: ```^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:!$&*\^\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:!$&*\^\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$```

Comment: i have refer your and add some my logic and it worked for me .Thank u !!